# How to optimize the mongodb query to work fast when having huge data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project where lacks of records will be present in some collections.
I need to write a query to get the data using pagination options to display in the table in frontend. So for pagination I'm using `mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2` npm module. But when I'm trying to run a particular query it's taking almost 6 to 7 minutes to return the response. I'm confused on what would be the issue here and how to optimize the query to get the response fast. And is there any alternative to provide pagination for mongodb queries.

This is the query I'm using.

```
let assetAggregate = Assets.aggregate();
    assetAggregate.match(extraData)
                    .lookup({
                        from: "tickets",
                        localField: "_id",
                        foreignField: "assets",
                        as: "ticket_assets"
                    })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"locations",
                        localField:"location",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"locationData"
                    })
                    .unwind({ 'path': '$locationData', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"user_dropdowns",
                        localField:"category",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"categoryData"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$categoryData', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"user_dropdowns",
                        localField:"type",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"typeData"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$typeData', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"admin_dropdowns",
                        localField:"asset_status",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"assetStatusData"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$assetStatusData', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"user_dropdowns",
                        localField:"condition",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"assetCondition"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$assetCondition', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"stores",
                        localField:"deployedAt",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"deployedStore"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$deployedStore', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"company_contacts",
                        localField:"assignedObj.allottedTo",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"assignedEmployee"
                    })
                    .unwind( { 'path': '$assignedEmployee', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true })
                    .lookup({
                        from:"locations",
                        localField:"using_location",
                        foreignField:"_id",
                        as:"assetUsingLocation"
                    })
                    .sort({"createdAt":-1})
                    .project({
                        "_id":1, "asset_name":1,"asset_code":1,
                        "status" : 1,"createdAt" : 1,"assetId": 1,
                        "location": {"$ifNull": ["$locationData", null]},
                        "category" : {"$ifNull": ["$categoryData", null]},
                        "type" : {"$ifNull": ["$typeData", null]},
                        "asset_status" : {"$ifNull": ["$assetStatusData", null]},
                        "ticketCount": {"$size": "$ticket_assets"},
                        "deployedAt": {"$ifNull": ["$deployedStore", null]},
                        "assignedTo": {"$ifNull": [{"fullName":"$assignedEmployee.fullName","_id":"$assignedEmployee._id"}, null]},
                        "condition": {"$ifNull": ["$assetCondition", null]},
                        "using_location": {"$ifNull": ["$assetUsingLocation", null]},
                        "predictive_maintenance": 1,"maintenanceValidationData": 1,
                        "allocationValidationData": 1,"purchasedFrom":1,
                        "warrantyDue":1, "lifeTime":1, "purchaseDate":1, "asset_price":1
                    });
        
    [err, assets] = await to(Assets.aggregatePaginate(assetAggregate,options));
```

Comment: 9 `$lookup` and 7 `$unwind`, maybe the problem is the design... are you sure MongoDB is the best DB for the project?

Comment: yes, mongodb is the best db for this. need to look into the lookups and unwinds. Is there any other alternative to ```mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2``` to implement pagination?

Comment: I don't think there is a magic library that will fix a 6 minute query. The query itself is massive, and beyond the scope of an online forum. You may be able to improve it with indexes and de-normalization of data. Possibly splitting it into multiple smaller queries. Or get the requirements re-evaluated to see if any of this data can be omitted or lazy loaded.

Comment: All the heavy work is done to populate empty fields with data from related documents, but the fallback is still to have these fields null if not present in the other document.  Is this fixed in new documents, and only a problem in the older ones?